# ssl-cert package (self signed certificates) for rpm/fedora

Tags: ubuntu, debian, redhat, fedora, rpm

In Debian/Ubuntu, my `deb` packages depend on the `ssl-cert` package, to provide some self-signed https certificates, if nothing else. From the [Debian page](http://packages.debian.org/sid/ssl-cert):

> This package enables unattended installs of packages that need to
>   create SSL certificates.
>
> It is a simple wrapper for OpenSSL's certificate request utility that
>   feeds it with the correct user variables.

Is there a similar package for rpm / Fedora?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that installing the `mod_ssl` package will automatically create some self-signed certificates, with an out of the box configuration file

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
```

Works great, no need to manually create certificates. The config looks like this:

```
#   Server Certificate:
# Point SSLCertificateFile at a PEM encoded certificate.  If
# the certificate is encrypted, then you will be prompted for a
# pass phrase.  Note that a kill -HUP will prompt again.  A new
# certificate can be generated using the genkey(1) command.
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt

#   Server Private Key:
#   If the key is not combined with the certificate, use this
#   directive to point at the key file.  Keep in mind that if
#   you've both a RSA and a DSA private key you can configure
#   both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA ciphers, etc.)
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key

#   Server Certificate Chain:
#   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
#   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
#   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
#   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
#   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
#   certificate for convinience.
#SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/server-chain.crt

#   Certificate Authority (CA):
#   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
#   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
#   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
#SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Comment: Thanks!. I didn't have to create dummy certs manually to test functionality after installing mod_ssl for apache in Linux. Note: I Installed mod_ssl using yum. I guess part of the installation includes the dummy certs. If you copy mod_ssl manually from other machine o location you still have to create the cers manually.

Answer (score 3):

The Fedora `openssl` package includes `/etc/pki/tls/certs/make-dummy-crt`, which can be used for generating self-signed certificates.  For example:

```
# cd /etc/pki/tls/certs
# ./make-dummy-cert mydummy.crt
# ls
ca-bundle.crt  ca-bundle.trust.crt  make-dummy-cert  Makefile  mydummy.crt
```